# Unable to update table using python function

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

iam trying to update a personal details table using the function below but it is not updating. It show that the person's details were updated successfully but the contents remains the same.

```py
#======= Update Function =================
def update_data(self):
    if self.var_Gender.get()=="Select Gender" or self.var_FirstName.get()=="" or self.var_LastName.get()=="" or self.var_Nationality.get()=="" or self.var_HomeAddress.get=="" or self.var_Occupation.get=="":
        messagebox.showerror("Error","All fields are required",parent=self.root)
    else:
        try:
            Update=messagebox.askyesno("Update","Do you want to update this person's details",parent=self.root)
            if Update>0:
                conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",username="root",password="tupsy@5050",database="details")
                my_cursor=conn.cursor()
                my_cursor.execute(
                    "update intel set Gender=%s,FirstName=%s,LastName=%s,Nationality=%s,Occupation=%s,HomeAddress=%s,PhoneNo=%s,Email=%s where Nationality=%s",
                    (
                        self.var_Gender.get(),
                        self.var_FirstName.get(),
                        self.var_LastName.get(),
                        self.var_Nationality.get(),
                        self.var_Occupation.get(),
                        self.var_HomeAddress.get(),
                        self.var_PhoneNo.get(),
                        self.var_Email.get(),
                        self.var_radio2.get()
                    )
                )
            else:
                if not Update:
                    return

            messagebox.showinfo("success","Person's details successfully updated",parent=self.root)
            conn.commit()
            self.fetch_data()
            conn.close()

        except Exception as es:
            messagebox.showerror("Error",f"Due To:{str(es)}",parent=self.root)
```

i tried checking all the parameters but they are just okay

Comment: Do you really seek to update the "gender" of every person from your given "nation"?

Answer (score 0):

In your query, try to enclose all string placeholders with double quotes `\"\"`.
The backslash are mandatory for escaping double quotes in string.

```
UPDATE intel SET 
Gender=\"%s\", FirstName=\"%s\", LastName=\"%s\", Nationality=\"%s\", Occupation=\"%s\", HomeAddress=\"%s\", PhoneNo=\"%s\", Email=\"%s\" 
WHERE Nationality=\"%s\"
```